# how to add hashmap in google maps android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

how to add hastmap to passing data from infowindow?

I want to display data from markers to new activity with the name of the mysql database

i want to replace it with hstmap, so that i can give more information when user press infowindow on markers

```
 private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title, final String keterangan) {
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(title);
    markerOptions.snippet(keterangan);
    gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Navigator.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
            i.putExtra("keterangan", marker.getSnippet());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Define hashmap
private HashMap<Marker, MyMarker>  markerHashMap=new HashMap<>();

//put all markers
markerHashMap.put(marker,mymaker);

gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
     if(markerHashMap!=null){
        MyMarker myMarker=markerHashMap.get(marker);
        Intent i=new Intent(Navigator.this,ScrollingActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("title",myMarker.getTitle());
        i.putExtra("keterangan",myMarker.getSnippt());
        startActivity(i);
        }
      }
    });
}


//put your data according your requirement
public class MyMarker {
    private String title, snippt;
    private double lat, lng;

    public MyMarker(String title, String snippt, double lat, double lng) {
        this.title = title;
        this.snippt = snippt;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
       }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSnippt() {
        return snippt;
    }

    public void setSnippt(String snippt) {
        this.snippt = snippt;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
       return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
      this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```